# Loop through variables, increment by 10 and create new variable

Tags: php

I have $amounts eg. 31; 48; 57; 63; 79; 84 and 95

What I would like to do is loop through each “$amount”, and if they are above 50, create variable that adds 1 for each 10 increment

Eg.

```
$amount(57) = +1    
$amount(63) = +2    
$amount(79) = +3    
$amount(84) = +4     
$amount(95) = +5
```

UPDATED VERSION:

**Apologies for the vague question.**

I have

```
$amount = array(end($percentage));
```

eg. 47, 63, 79, 95

What I would like to have is another variable to be created eg. $to_add if $amount > 50.
Then for each $amount >= 50 add 1 to the $to_add

Should look like:

```
$amount(47)  =  NULL ($to_add = 0)
$amount(50)  =  $to_add = 1 – *WOULD HAVE BEEN*
$amount(63)  =  $to_add = 2
$amount(79)  =  $to_add = 3
$amount(80)  =  $to_add = 4 – *WOULD HAVE BEEN*
$amount(95)  =  $to_add = 5
```

Thanks for the input thus far - I am testing the feedback I have already received - thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Is $amount some kind of array?

Comment: your question is a little vague, could you explain more ?

Comment: Okay wait I dont get it now. IF the $amount is above 50, you want to create a variable that adds 1 for each 10. So that's the value 5 for 57 and 6 for 63? Or what? I dont get it.

Comment: Or do you want to add +1 to the SAME variable everytime the $amount is above 50? Like in your example

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat like this:

```
$array=array();
$i=0;
foreach($amounts as $amount){
   if($amount>50){
      $value=floor($amount/10);
      $array[$i]=$value;
      $i++;
   }
}
var_dump($array);
```

Now `$array` contains the values you want. You have to adapt the code to your code since I have no idea what `$amount` is(I assume values of an array)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), then I check if the value is over 50 and if yes I add 1 for every 10)

```
<?php

    $amount = [31, 48, 57, 63, 79, 84, 95];

    print_r($amount);
    $amount = array_map(function($v){
        if($v / 50 >= 1)
            return ceil($v + ($v-50)/10);
        return $v;
    }, $amount);

    print_r($amount);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 48 [2] => 57 [3] => 63 [4] => 79 [5] => 84 [6] => 95 )
Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => 48 [2] => 58 [3] => 65 [4] => 82 [5] => 88 [6] => 100 )
```